# c# HttpClient - Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am connecting to a server from .net core 3.1 app by using `HttpClient` to download 5 files in parallel, but when I send the http request through the method `SendAsync` and trying to read the bytes that the server emits through the response stream, I get the following exception:

> Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream

The following code is for sending the Http request message to download a file:

```
// Send DownloadRequest
public async Task RequestDownload(string fileid, string tokenauth, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    // create request message
    var request = GetRequest(fileid, tokenauth);

    // create createhttpclient
    HttpClient _client = HttpClientFactory.CreateHttpClient();

    // send request
    var response = await _client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, cancellationToken);

    // get response stream
    using (var responsestream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
    {
        using(Stream copystream = new FileStream(fileid, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write))
        {
            responsestream.CopyTo(copystream);
        }
    }

    var ausresult = await ParseDownloadResponse(response);
}
```

Method to build `HttpRequestMessage`:

```
// Create httpRequestMessage
public static HttpRequestMessage GetRequest(string fileid, string authorizationtoken)
{
    // Build uri connection
    var uri = new System.Uri("https://www.downloadserver.com/GetFile");

    var strfieldid = "{\"fileId\":\"" + fileId + "\"}";
    var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strfieldid);
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage()
                      {
                          Method = HttpMethod.Post,
                          RequestUri = uri,
                          Content = new ByteArrayContent(body)
                      };

    request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", authorizationtoken);

    return request;
}
```

The `HttpClient` object is reused for each download requests (5), therefore the
same `HttpClient` instance is used in parallel, in addition to the http client being initialized as follows with an `HttpClientHandler`:

Method to create `HttpClient`:

```
// Get HttpClient
public static HttpClient CreateHttpClient(int timeout)
{
    if (_client == null)
    {
        // create http handler to allow Auto Redirect
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler()
                          {
                              AllowAutoRedirect = true,
                              UseProxy = false
                          };
        // create httpclient
        _client = new HttpClient(handler);

        _client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Timeout.Infinite);

        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    }

    return _client;
}
```

Finally when I download a single file, the exception is not generated and the download is completed successfully, but when all 5 files are downloaded in parallel at the same time, the exception Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream occurs.

Any thoughts will be greatly appreciated.

Best

Comment: Its likely nothing to do with your code, and everything to do with the policies and coders on the other end. You may need to speak with them, or not throttle the resource so much

Comment: Did you create a unit test to test your end? If not, that would be my starting point.

Comment: What happens if you download the files in serial instead of parallel?  I do not know how you can send one request and then process the return in parallel.  The data is coming serial so how do you split serial data into parallel data?